# What word would you use to describe a local McDonalds?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

McDonald's is a global chain, which has thousands of restaurants worldwide. However, let's say, I am visiting a local McDonald's at 28th and Main (hypothetical). I can just say,

> I am going to McDonald's at 28th.

I am looking for an alternative expression, can I say the following?

> I am going to **franchise of McDonald's**.
> I am going to **restaurant of McDonald's**.
> I am going to **chain of McDonald's**.
> I am going to **establishment of McDonald's**.

Regards other brands such as Apple, I can use the words of store/outlet for their retail establishment.

I am not sure what word I use for McDonald's.

Comment: "on 28th street" or "at 28th and main",  but not "at 28th".

Comment: Aside from which choice of word is natural, all of the words you've suggested are countable names, so they need an article: **a** franchise, **a** restaurant, etc.

Answer (score 3):

"Going to McDonald's" is the best way.  No need for an alternative.

"Going to a Mcdonald's restaurant" is okay - assuming you are going to eat. But most people know about McDonald's and so the word "restaurant" is a bit redundant.

"Going to a Mcdonald's franchise" - if you are going to meet with the manager to learn about the business.

If you are specifying the address, an article is indicated:

> I'm going to the McDonald's on 28th and Main.

Comment: Is outlet a correct word to describe McDoanlds? I generally use outlet for brands such as Macy's/Target, not for a restaurant.

Comment: The best word is still just "McDonalds".    Outlet is a rather technical-sounding word for describing the function in a business model, not for talking about a place to eat cheap burgers.

Comment: Actually, you are misunderstanding my question. McDonald's is just an example. Say, I am an economist. I want to say, this unit/outlet of mcdonald's makes the most money. what would be the most appropriate word here?

Comment: No,  I understand your question fine.  It is about McDonalds.  You ask "What word can I use for McDonald's?"   And the context is not about an economist, it is about "Going to a local McDonald's"  probably to eat.

Comment: I would call an individual unit of a large company a _branch_.